# Any Chance for me to install ubuntu on laptop Asus n61 JQ-X1?

Tags: installation, drivers, asus

I bought this laptop (ASUS N61JQ -X1) 2 years ago,till now i'm using window 7 64bit
i wanna change OS for my laptop and Ubuntu is an advice that "google" gave me,
but im not sure that Ubuntu has all drivers for my laptop or not because there are no Linux/Ubuntu driver for my model from ASUS
http://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/217/N61Jq/8/

please help me, tell me if i have any chance on this

Comment: You may not need any drivers. Ubuntu supports a lot of hardware out of the box.  I have an ASUS laptop with Ubuntu installed and I didn't need any drivers (though it is a different model). Try a live DVD or USB without installing.  If everything works you can install if not you can ask specific questions about any problems you are having before you commit to installing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install any specific drivers for (audio,video) after installing ubuntu.But You must have to install specific drivers for graphics,wireless,mobile broadband.It was so better to try a *ubuntu live cd*.